# How to construct an orthogonal coordinate system from a smooth planar curve?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given a planar curve $$\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2, t\mapsto \gamma(t) \text{, normalized to } |\gamma'(t)|\equiv1,$$
the tangential vector $$T(t) = \gamma'(t)$$
and the normal vector $$N(t) = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}T(t) \perp T(t)$$
(note that since $T^2\equiv 1$, for $T'(t)\neq 0$ we have $N(t)=\kappa T'(t)$ where $|\kappa|=1/|T'(t)|$, see also [Frenet-Serret formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)) can be defined and considered *one* curve of constant $s$ for some coordinate system $(e_1(t,s),e_2(t,s))$, i.e.

$$e_1(t,s_0) = T(t),\quad e_2(t,s_0) = N(t)$$

> How can the general $(e_1(t,s),e_2(t,s))$ be obtained from this, and is the obtained coordinate system unique?

I assume $\gamma$ must be closed or infinite in order to uniquely span the entire $\mathbb R^2$?

As an example, if $\gamma$ is an ellipse, the sought procedure should yield an elliptic coordinate system, while for a straight line this would simply yield the Cartesian coordinate system.